# Attaching a camera video feed to html in Adobe Air

Tags: javascript, html, air, adobe, videodisplay

I am using the Adobe AIR SDK to develop an HTML/JavaScript app that needs to record video. I'm not using Flex or Flash Builder which can use `<mx:VideoDisplay />`

I know how to attach the camera video feed to a new window object via `nativeWindow.stage`. Is it possible to do something similar in a section of the html or an iframe? Or is there an html tag that AIR interprets like the `<mx:VideoDisplay />` tag in ActionScript?

Comment: I think I figured out a way using an embedded Flash file and ExternalInterface. We're testing it now. Keep your fingers crosses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the answer was not to attach the video feed to the HTML, but to load it in a Flash Player file. We ended up embedding JWPlayer into the app and having it play the video stream from the media server. However, something similar can be done to have a sort of video chat app. You can create a SWF file that implements the ExternalInterface class in ActionScript so you can expose necessary functions to JavaScript.